# Accessing Ant properties in Gradle Task / Groovy function?

Tags: gradle, ant

I am trying to use the ant.uptodate function in a gradle function, to check if some files have changed.

```
task generateXMLBeans {
    ant.uptodate(property: "xsdFileChanges", targetfile: "lib/xmlBeans.jar") {
            srcfiles(dir: 'protocol') {
                include(name: '*.xsd')
            }
    }
    if(ant.properties.xsdFileChanges == "false") {
        ant.taskdef(name: 'xmlbean', classname: 'org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.XMLBean',
            classpath: configurations.xmlbeans.asPath)
            ant.xmlbean(
                javasource: "1.5", 
                failonerror: "true",
                fork: "yes",
                memoryMaximumSize: "512M",
                memoryInitialSize: "64M",
                destfile: "lib/xmlBeans.jar",
                classpath: configurations.xmlbeans.asPath){
                    fileset(dir: 'protocol') {
                        include(name: '*.xsdconfig')
                        include(name: 'hmiprotocol.xsd')
                    }
                }    
    }
}
```

But the variable `ant.properties.xsdFileChanges` is **`null`**.

I tried to put the `ant.uptodate` function in a separate function, with the same result.

When I call the task with `--debug` function, I can see that the ant.uptodate function works generally.

```
14:40:50.947 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:uptodate] hmiprotocol_systemlog.xsd omitted as D:\workspace_201912\ProjectX\lib\xmlBeans.jar is up to date.
14:40:50.948 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:uptodate] hmiprotocol_testdetails.xsd omitted as D:\workspace_201912\ProjectX\lib\xmlBeans.jar is up to date.
```

Has anyone any idea, how I can access the ant property correctly?

Comment: if you have a boolean in gradle, you can check it by either
if (boolVal){ mycoolstuff } 
or  if (boolVal == true)  ...   Testing against a string literal is incorrect in either case.

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/ant.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't related to using Ant from within Gradle; it's just how Ant's `uptodate` property works. The specified property isn't set to `false` if the file isn't up to date. It's simply not set at all. A few other Ant tasks, such as `condition` use this same convention.

A quick example you can try with Ant itself, given that you have both a build.xml and build.gradle file in the same directory:

```
<target name="default">
    <uptodate property="uptodate1" targetfile="build.xml" srcfile="build.gradle" />

    <echo>${uptodate1}</echo>

    <uptodate property="uptodate2" targetfile="build.gradle" srcfile="build.xml" />

    <echo>${uptodate2}</echo>
</target>
```

Output (may be reversed depending on modified times):

```
default:
     [echo] true
     [echo] ${uptodate2}
```

Comment: You are right. The uptodate function property will never be set to false. The only possible values are true or null.